# How to reduce the waiting time in the Firebug net panel?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, firebug

I am working on gwt application with google app engine as a server. I have put the logs and appstat filter, so that i could know that what is the latency time.
Suppose if i open a link it is showing that 118ms for appstats (real=118ms) and 90ms for coming back through my login filter, so it is totally 208ms but in the firebug net panel it is showing 705ms for onload for the first request,
Any body have any idea, please let me know.

Thanks 
MSNaidu

Comment: Have you considered that the extra 500 ms is the latency from your client to Google's servers?

Comment: yes, i mentioned that through appstat filter, this filter is showing me the time to get the response form google server.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a really difficult to figure our whether firebug is recording incorrectly or if there  is genuine lag. You should try cross confirming by using [Chrome SpeedTracer](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/) and Chrome's Dev Tools Network, [Timeline](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline) and Audits features.